# Why use 'lib' vs 'src' directory names in JavaScript? Which is 'standard'?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

There are many popular JavaScript libraries and applications on GitHub and some put their raw source code in a `/src` directory, and others in a `/lib` directory.

I'm leaning towards the developers having done this depending on which languages they were taught growing up. So I see a lot of JavaScript developers use `/lib` (who also normally end up putting their packaged JS into a `/bin` directory). Meanwhile I often observe that those who use `/src` output their packaged JS into a `/dist` folder instead.

**What is considered the standard pattern for JavaScript, `src` or `lib`.** Maybe there isn't a right or wrong answer at all.

Comment: I've seen a lot of projects with Javascript files in a `/js` directory. Does it matter?

Comment: There is no technical difference sure, but trying to establish a pattern + convention.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/tracker1/59f2c13044315f88bee9

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Interesting question, but it seems to me that some developers just take it by their own **worldview**.

It also depends on the project:

Some projects are built with smaller components, which are just little pieces of the main functionality: `lib`.

`lib/independent-pieces.js`

Other projects are monolithic, the components depend on each other: `src`.

`src/this-is-all-for-this-project-and-depend-on-each-other.js`

For third-party libraries, it's common to use `vendor`.

```
vendor/bootstrap/
vendor/d3/
```

Comment: Yes I think it's more worldview too, I see `lib` used without a corresponding `src`, even in apps that aren't componentized. I guess it's just a pattern that stuck one day and some people still use it.

Comment: What would you say about the comment on the second answer by @nelsonic saying that `src` is uncompiled source code and `lib` compiled respectively ready to use code? This seems quite different.

Comment: I myself am also grappling with the distinction (src vs lib) when it comes to node packages. In other languages, I believe the src dir is typically used for (source code) files that are meant to be compiled into literal binary executables. The problem with js is that there typically isn't even a such thing as `bin`ary or `src` (source) files strictly speaking (unless your definition of source and binary includes mere transpilation). So if your node package doesn't "compile" anything (e.g. doesn't use typescript or babel or web pack etc.), then it would seem improper to have a `src` directory.

Answer (score 5):

- `/node_modules` - for 3rd party libraries.
- `/lib` or `/vendor`- suggested putting your libraries which is not required for compilation.
- `/src` - for your code
  source

Comment: which "Best Practice" book was this in...? In a typical "universal JS" app 3rd party libraries are kept in `node_modules` and `/lib` is used for your own code that does not require compilation. `/src` would be used for ES6 code that needs to be "_compiled_" ("_transpiled_")

Comment: @nelsonic Actually, I agree with you. Edited answer in accordance with your comment.

Comment: @nelsonic spot-on, however transpilation and compilation of JavaScript-esque files can occur for several reasons (e.g. typescript -> js, jsx -> js) other than simply the back-porting of ES6 code to older environments/runtimes